# Why is Status 'non subscriptable' and how do I fix it? Python Tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to use the code I made below to fetch the media url of a video in a tweet when someone replies to that tweet with my @handle:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        clean_data = json.loads(data)
        tweetId = clean_data['id']
        tweet_name = clean_data['user']['screen_name']
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("consumer_key", "consumer_secret")
            auth.set_access_token("access_token", "access_token_secret")
            api = tweepy.API(auth)
            mediaupload_id = clean_data['in_reply_to_status_id']
            origtweet_media = api.get_status(mediaupload_id)
            print()
            print(origtweet_media)
            native_media = origtweet_media['extended_entities']['media'][0]['video_info']
            tweet_media = native_media['variants'][0]['url']
            print(tweet_media)

def setUpAuth():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("consumer_key", "consumer_secret")
    auth.set_access_token("access_token", "access_token_secret")
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    return api, auth

def followStream():
    api, auth = setUpAuth()
    listener = StdOutListener()
    stream = Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(track=["@YOUR_TWITTER_HANDLE"], is_async=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    followStream()
```

Everything seems to be set up well, but when I run the code, and someone replies to a tweet with a video in it (the person replying mentioning my @handle), I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'Status' object is not subscriptable
    native_media = origtweet_media['extended_entities']['media'][0]['video_info']
```

Why is 'Status' non-subscriptable? And is there a way I can fix this issue, so it successfully grabs the video url (`tweet_media`)?

Someone please help me!

Comment: "Not subscriptable" means you've got something that is neither a list nor a dictionary, so you can't use `variable[index]` or `variable[key]` to dereference it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED!

After closely looking at the `print`ed `origtweet_media`, I noticed that the tweet info was inside `_json=()`. So I added `._json` onto the end of `origtweet_media = api.get_status(mediaupload_id)` as that just isolates the json section, allowing me to find the video url for `tweet_media`. Here's what the new updated line looks like:

```
origtweet_media = api.get_status(mediaupload_id)._json
```

and then it worked successfully!